# HTML- HREF Tag inside a Button

Tags: php, html, zend-framework2

This is my button code, which has a reference tag, and the URL takes me to an index action correctly

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><a style="color:white" href="<?php echo $this->basePath('calendar/details/index').'?month='.$this->previousMonth?>"> Previous </a></button>
```

and this is the picture of the button

[image: Preview of current Button]

The problem is that only the text **Previous** on button is clickable, other than that any click on the blue part of the button does not work. How to make the whole area of the button work, without disturbing the URL?

Comment: try adding the class `class="btn btn-primary"` in a tag

Comment: tried it, i increased the size of the button and the problem remained the same, and also i am using zendframe work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="btn btn-primary" style="color: white" href="#">Previous</a>
```

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" style="color: white" href="<?php echo $this->basePath('calendar/details/index').'?month='.$this->previousMonth?>">Previous</a>
```

Comment: Great, thanks it works, all i did was to remove the button tag and replace it with <a> tag.